# Device Management on Android

Tags: android, device-admin, device-management

**TL;DR**

1. Device Management APIs or EMM solution for preventing app uninstall and whitelist/blacklisting applications from Play Store?
2. Is it possible to create custom EMM solution without going through Google Review?

To elaborate my scenario, I have 4 different applications say A, B, C and D. Now C and D both application depend on A and B both.

C -> Requires A and B

D -> Requires A and B

This is an enterprise deployment and I want to force several device management policies in addition to prevent removing application A and B. I have looked over [Device Management APIs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) which is now [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/android/work/device-admin-deprecation) and [EMM Provider documentations](https://developers.google.com/android/work/overview). Now what is the better solution for this scenario and if I am selecting EMM Provider over Device Management APIs, does that mean that the company will need to purchase EMM solution from one of their partners only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the new Google [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management/) to manage your devices and force install your apps. This API is free and anyone can use it.

There is currently a default quota of 10 devices, but Google will lift this quota as long as your use case is legitimate. For that you just need to apply to join the EMM Community, don't worry about the requirements they don't apply when you develop a solution for your own company.

Comment: Thanks @Fred, so basically, as long as I develop solution for own company/internal use, I do not have to partner a EMM provider and fulfill all those requirements and the quota of 10 devices will be lifted as well? I am planning to deploy this solution for 5k+ devices.

Comment: That's right. And I'd recommend joining the EMM Community early so you get access to the support forum.

Comment: Hey @Fred, regarding joining EMM Community, do they still require the implementation of these APIs on a backend and review of the final solution? We have a very limited timeframe and was hoping for a quick replacement of Device Admin APIs. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you develop a solution for your own company there will likely be no review and no expectation that you build a backend or UI. However note that the Android Management API is a Cloud-based API, it is called from a server (or a script if that's easier for you), not from an app on the device.